# Handling Long Processing Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

In my program I have some processing-intensive code that takes about a minute to process some strings for my app. However, in the corona simulator, my app locks up and says it is not responding until the processing completes then it will act normal. So my question is if there exists a way to notify the phone in some way to tell it that the app is not locked up but merely processing data so the users won't think it is failing and quit the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an event listener to show something and remove it when it finishes. I have done one for a simple touch event.

```
local function rotate(event)
  if event.phase=="began" then
  contactName= display.newText( "test", 185, 100, native.systemFont, 24)

 end

  if event.phase=="ended" then
   contactName:removeSelf()
  end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", rotate)
```

If you don't have any listener for that function simply show a text that something is happening and the text value tied to your process results.
If not working tell us what is your exact process so something may work for it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to show an activity indicator.  See:  http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/setActivityIndicator.html

This will tell the user the app is busy.  However, when people get spinning cursors for long periods of time, they think things are hung up.  If you can break it into chunks that will help.

You might want to consider coroutines.  Coroutines are documented on the Lua site and Corona SDK supports them.  We are planning a tutorial on them for Tuesday 2/10 (assuming it doesn't get bumped).  http://coronalabs.com/blog/